# Entity Framework Error: Could not find the conceptual model type for X

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

I have a demo project with two folders:

```
Data
   /DbContext
   /EntityFramework
```

Both have an EDMX, and for the DbContext folder, I have a DbContext generator T4 template setup.  Whenever I try to run my  DbContext samples, I get an error saying "Could not find the conceptual model type for X", that it can't load the metadata for an entity defined in the EntityFramework folder's EDMX... Why in the world would it do that?  I did not setup any T4 template for the EDMX in the EntityFramework folder, and did not copy the EDMX over,  but created a new one in the DbContext.  I verified the connection string is mapping to the correct EDMX...

Any ideas why I get the error then: Could not find the conceptual model type for X?

Thanks.

Comment: This exception happens when you try to get a C-Space EDM type for an O-Space object. In your case I assume there is a mismatch between the data in edmx file and your object model. This post can give you some ideas: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/. Also, do you have a stack trace for the exception? It could make it easier to figure out what is happening.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268036/edmx-for-legacy-code-and-code-first-for-new-development-together-in-one-mvc-pr

Comment: make sure the connection string contains the metadata reference to the conceptual model as shown in @GáborPlesz link.