# Error when using two EDMX files (one dbContext, the other regular EDMX)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, objectcontext

For reference, please see [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086834/entity-framework-error-could-not-find-the-conceptual-model-type-for-x).  I have the EXACT same error.  It's not related to using Code-First by Mistake.  Two EDMX files (one with plain old CodeGen, the other with dBContext T4 code gen), two DIFFERENT namespaces, different conection strings, etc.  you get the idea.  The DBContext model is throwing an error when an attempt is made to access the data.

So, when accessing `NameSpace.Models.MyEntities.ObjectSet` (the dbContext T4-template generated objects) I get the following error:

> Could not find the conceptual model type for
>   `AnotherNameSpace.Models.MyObjectClass`.

Where `AnotherNameSpace.Models.MyObjectClass` refers to a completely different EDMX in a different folder/namespace.  I can't find ANY references at all to `AnotherNameSpace.Models.MyObjectClass` anywhere in any of the t4-generated files, etc. These EDMX file(s) were not copied from each other.  LITERALLY, the ONLY thing the EDMX files have in common is that they ultimately point to the same database (though they do NOT share a connection string).

When Attempting to access the ObjectSet above, it throws the error that is classified as a `System.ArgumentException`:

```
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetEdmSpaceType[T](T objectSpaceType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappings()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at GratisWeb.Areas.App.Controllers.WorkplanController.Index() in B:\eGrATIS\Code\src\GratisWeb\Areas\App\Controllers\WorkplanController.cs:line 30
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: Are these two models in one assembly? By "plain old codegen" you mean that entities are derived from the EntityObject class and there are attributes (like EdmEntityTypeAttribute or EdmPropertyAttribute) all over the place?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is two separate assembly in two EDMX, but it is very difficult to maintain. Here are the details: [EDMX for legacy code _and_ Code First for new development together in one MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268036/edmx-for-legacy-code-and-code-first-for-new-development-together-in-one-mvc-pr)